# How to calculate efficiently the sum between two elements on a vector

Tags: python, vector

I have a mathematic problem, someone asking me how to obtain efficiently the sum of several elements of a vector onto a program in python for example.

For example, we have a vector (v) with n elements (n=100000000 and n is a random real number) and we want to calculate the sum between v(10) and v(100000) and after, between v(8) and v(100). In fact, we want to calculate efficiently the sum of elements between two elements A and B with (A < B).

I'm not looking for an answer with directly a code. I'm looking for a mathematic explanation to understand this problem which is certainly a basic concept in vector efficient calculus.

Comment: The question boils down to "How do I represent a vector?", and there are numerous libraries that do this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to calculate in first a new vector (w) which is the cumulated sum of the vector v. So, if we want the sum between v(1) and v(1000), the answer is w(1000) and if we want the sum between v(10) and v(1000), the answer will be w(1000)-w(10-1). The only low calcul will be the cumulated sum.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to build a memoisation table:

```
def sums(L):
    answer = {i:{j:0 for j in range(i,len(L))} for i in range(len(L))}
    for i,num in enumerate(L):
        answer[i][i] = L[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
            answer[i][j] = answer[i][j-1] + L[j]

    return answer
```

Then query the table as follows:

```
table = sums(my_vector)
print(table[8][100])
```

Comment: OP states: I'm not looking for an answer with directly a code. I'm looking for a mathematic explanation to understand this problem which is certainly a basic concept in vector efficient calculus.

Comment: But if you have huge datas, building a memoisation table would be huge right ?

I just think about this with a friend:
what if I build a unitary vertically vector (u) with a size about the number of elements that we want to summed.
A is the minimal element we want and B the max (8 and 100 to take the same value than previous). So, u = zeros(B-A+1,1)+1;
And then, the sum will be : v(1,a:b)*u
is that the efficient way to do this calculus with no memorisation of datas ?

Comment: @LionelMattéo: the size of the table grows as n^2, for `n` elements in the vector. If you could post (edit your original post) a small example, I'd be happy to take another look at this

Comment: Actually I find the answer, while we want to calculate so much sums, if we use the vector calculus as I said it on my last comment, it will take a really long time.
The solution is to calculate in first a new vector which is the cumulated sum of the vectore v. So, if we want the sum between v(1) and v(1000), the answer is v(1000) and if we want the sum between v(10) and v(1000), the answer will be v(1000)-v(10-1). The only low calcul will be the cumulated sum.
Thank's by the way for your help ! :)